# mysql_affected_rows() returns -100

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a very funny problem with my code. Basically the first time when I run the code I get the correct result from the `mysqli_effected_rows()` function. But the second time I run the same script it keeps giving me "-100"

If I delete all the records in the table and run the code again I get the correct result from `mysqli_effected_rows()` function.

is "-100" an error code ?

```
$count ="";

foreach($database as $key=>$value) {

  foreach($value as $field => $cell){

    if ($field =='itemid') {
        echo "the item id is $cell <br />";
        $col1 = $cell ;
    }
    elseif ($field =='title') {

        echo "the title is $cell<br />";
        $col2 = $cell;
    }
    elseif ($field =='starttime') {

        echo "the start time is $cell<br />";
        $col3 = $cell;
    }
  }
  $dbquery = "INSERT INTO cordless_drill(itemid,title,starttime) VALUES ('$col1','$col2','$col3')";
mysqli_query($dbc,$dbquery);

  $count += mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
}
echo $count ;
```

Comment: Possibly a unique key constraint violation? Can you show your `cordless_drill` table definition, including keys and constraints please.

Comment: Is the correct number supposed to be 100? mysqli_affected_rows returns -1 if the query fails, so if there are 100 inserts failing you will get -100. Presumably you've got a primary key somewhere which won't allow you to insert a duplicate row when you run the script again.

Comment: if database have 100 row and each row returned -1 so the result will be -100 try to echo the query and see it.

Comment: One hell of an echo in here.

Comment: itemid  bigint(20) PRI

Comment: So itemid is a primary key? That's why all your inserts are failing when you run it a second time as you can't insert duplicate itemids. This is also why it works properly when you delete all the data first.

Comment: thnx Peter, can u please tell me what steps i need to take before trying to insert data into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the number of affected rows by the last `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` or `DELETE` query associated with `link_identifier`. The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if `mysql_connect()` was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an `E_WARNING level` error is generated. Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed.
Before attempting  `$count += mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);` just try to echo the values of `mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)` ... and check any warning occurs ....